# How does opensocial-jquery overcome the browser's inability to parse the results of a cross domain POST?

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain, opensocial

I was under the impression that you [needed a web proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) to parse the results of a cross-domain AJAX POST.

But apparently, you can accomplish this with [opensocial-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-jquery/wiki/Ajax#Sending_data_to_an_external_host).

Could someone please explain how opensocial-jquery makes this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm... the very first sentence on the page you linked to explains it

From http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-jquery/wiki/Ajax

> All requests generated by jQuery.ajax are relayed to the proxy gadget server. This frees up cross-domain restrictions and maintains compatibility.